# My assign on a table row not reflecting on the front end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have finally filtered and retrieved the rows I want in my table and assigned it a value, it outputs to the console properly but not rendered on the web page itself.

I have retrieved my rows into a variable row and assigned it another variable

```
var rows = [...$(".table td")].map(e => $(e).text().trim()).filter(e => e);
console.log(rows);
for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    //I have assigned it in the line below
    rows[i].text = dateArr[i];
    console.log(rows[i]);
}
```

Comment: and what is dateArr[i]  ???

Comment: `rows[i].text = dateArr[i];`? `rows[i]` are strings. What are you trying to achieve by adding a `text` property to them?

Comment: `rows[i].text = dateArr[i];`.. Regardless what dateArr is, this just won't work, since those are **strings**. In order to change the text, you need to work with the jQuery / javascript DOMElement reference.

Comment: Hi @briosheje, I am fairly new to javascript, but i am think since I have retrieved the rows I want, i can just assigned. dateArr[i] is an array of start-end date.

Comment: @MrJ, I am trying to assign the cells in the table that value of dateArr[i].

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, wouldn't you mind to do one step further and employ [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plug-in to fulfill your needs? Your first (so ES6) line of code completely not fitting to the rest of the code makes me think you could benefit a lot from available tools rather than developing your own.

Comment: @SneakyBastard I am csharp guy, my web dev skills are bit shaky, I have only learnt this much over this weekend, but I would into using the Data Tables as suggested.

Comment: As being said, you don't need to invent your own bicycle, you may go farther with available ones with much less effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in your console.log(rows);
you only get a new array of string with all TD values, not a pointer on each TD with a useless complicated code

```js
const newVals = [111,222,333];

document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td').forEach( (elmTD, idx)=>{
  elmTD.textContent=newVals[idx].toString()
})
```

```css
td { border:1px solid grey }
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
      <td> aaa </td>
      <td> bbb </td>
      <td> ccc </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All I can say is "forget jQuery and use javascript ES6" only because you already use arrow functions